# Error: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable on aws glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, xsd, aws-glue

I have been trying to use the spark library XSDToSchema on AWS glue to read xsd file but it gives me 'JavaPackage' object is not callable error

```
with open('example_xsd.xsd', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    xml_schema = f.read()
a = spark._jvm.com.databricks.spark.xml.util.XSDToSchema.read(xml_schema)
```

Then it gives this error:

> JavaPackage' object is not callable

[image: JavaPackage' object is not callable eror]

I tried run on my local machine turns out fine but when try it on glue aws (even glue 3.0 and 4.0) still has this error

Comment: I found out that by adding the spark-xml_2.12-0.16.0.jar to the jar dependent path it will work but then it start giving this error:
'py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:com.databricks.spark.xml.util.XSDToSchema.read.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/XmlSchemaCollection'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case solved:
We need to add the following jar files to the Dependent JARs path

- org.apache.ws.xmlschema_xmlschema-core-2.3.0.jar
- spark-xml_2.12-0.16.0.jar
- org.glassfish.jaxb_txw2-3.0.2.jar